# Force on current carrying conductor

Tags: magnetic-fields

I got this question from a talent search examination. I checked the answer keys and i had got it wrong. The answer is option D.

From the formula, F = BIL, force is directly proportional to the length of the structures, the magnetic field and current being constant. The lengths of each structure doesn't appear to be the same, 'l' here appears to be the widths of the structures instead of actual lengths, then how could they all experience the same force? I think that the answer should not be D.

Am i right? Is this question even correct?

[image: Figure]

Answer (score 1):

It seems that all four structures have the same width $\ell$. Think about approximating each of the current carrying wires by step-functions, such that the segments of the steps go along the horizontal ($x-$) direction and along the vertical ($y-$) direction.

To obtain such a step function, you can subdivide the interval $\ell$ into $n$ segments, and approximate the shape of the current carrying wire as piecewise constant (i.e. horizontal) within these segments. At the boundaries between the segments, there will be a vertical part connecting the wire parts belonging to neighboring segments.

Since the forces act in the plane normal to the magnetic field, and normal to the orientation of the step segments, you see that the forces acting in horizontal direction (caused by step segments in $y$-direction) cancel in all four cases. The forces acting in $y$-direction (caused by the step segments in $x$-direction), however, add up over a total width of $\ell$ in all four cases. Therefore, the resulting force acts in $y$-direction in all four cases, and it has the same magnitude.

The transition to the case of the continuous curves shown is the limit for infinitesimally small step size (if the step function is constructed as described above, this is the limit of $n\rightarrow\infty$). The conclusion remains the same.
Therefore, answer (D) is correct.

Comment: Can plz elaborate on step functions

Comment: *can you elaborate on it plz

Comment: @Hark: I added a suggestion, how such a 'step function' could be constructed. It is very similar to the elementary way of defining the area under a curve by approximating the curve by a piecewise constant function, and then taking the limit of infinitesimally small segments.

Comment: I get what you are saying, but i am in 10th grade. So this is supposed to be 10th grade question

Comment: Could there be a simpler explanation?